# How to efficiently extract street from a string

Tags: string, parsing

I need to extract street from apartment description. I don't necessarily need it with number (not every listing have it anyway), but it would be appreciated.

**MY 'SOLUTIONS'**
 1. Use regular expression. But then after reading many descriptions I realized that people often omit characteristic signs like writing 'street' equivalent before actual street name etc.
 2. Create list containing possible street names. Because I know in which city the apartments will be, I can download every street name from this city, load it and then try to match any word from description with streets stored in list (probably some kind of hash table). But descriptions can be quite long and streets can consist of few words. Then probably I need to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10979685/4307480) solution. Also address in description can have 1-2 characters miss-typed.
 3. Hand over this work to third-party map engine. Cut few words from string, send it to some map engine (i.e. Google Maps), if it doesn't make sense for it, then try next few words etc.

Is there any better solution?
I feel like I have to assume things like address will always be typed correctly etc., otherwise complexity will be unacceptably high.

EDIT:
Programming language - I asked it as a generic question, not specific to language. But I'm using Python
String format - there is no exact string format, because everyone writes description as he wants. Usually the localization is somewhere in the beginning, but that's not always the case.
Make different format - I can't, because I'm scraping this data from different sites.

Comment: there are a few unclear things in your question. which programming language are we talking about? what's the format of the string *exactly*? can you make concrete examples of possible inputs -> desired outputs?

Comment: If you really need it separated, maybe you need a different input for the street and one for the number / apartment description?

Comment: @blue Unfortunately I can't provide examples, the name is always surrounded by 'useless' information. See my edit.

Comment: A generic solution to this kind of problems is doing one first pass of data sanitization/normalization (remove extraneous pieces of information, discard malformed data, extract the bare minimum you need to work with from your dataset) and then a second pass to actually get the information you want (probably with a regex or multiple regexes, in your case) from the easier-to-work-with dataset.